# Rule Designer のインストールについて

Tags: eclipse, bluemix

お世話になっています。今般IBMのBLuemixでODMの動作を試してみたいと考えています。
第一歩としてRule Designerのインストールをしようとしたのですが、
マニュアルに、Eclipseのupdate site のロケーションの記載が存在せず、
とん挫しています。どなたか、正しいインストール手順をご存じの方がいらっしゃればご教示くださいお願いします。

参照：
[IBMのインストールマニュアル](https://www.eu-gb.bluemix.net/docs/services/rules/index.html#rulov002)

Answer (score 2):

確かに日本語版のドキュメントではURLの記載が抜けていますね。
英語版のドキュメントには下記URLの記述がありますので試してみてください。

http://businessrules-updates.ng.bluemix.net/